# Auth0 silent auth not working on mobile, works fine elsewhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, auth0

Pretty stuck with this one. I'm using Auth0's SPA-JS SDK and it works perfectly for the most part, but on mobile when I refresh the page it logs me out.

I get the error that says "login required", but no such error when on the desktop. On the desktop, I can refresh the page as much as I want with no issue.

I am not using the dev keys anymore for my social signups, and the issue occurs on email signup as well, so I don't think dev keys are the issue either.

Thanks.

Comment: Most probably the cookie was not sent when you are trying to perform the silent authentication or your session has expired (Seamless SSO). Can you check that the cookie settings in your device. I would test in multiple mobiles devices to understand the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the mobile browser (eg Chrome / Safari)?
Or a mobile webview?

The latter case will always give you a private browser session where cookies and session storage are both aggressively dropped.

If you're not using the mobile browser then the other scenarios require more work. Logins via some form of the system browser work best.

Also are you using local storage of OAuth 2.0 tokens? 
- if so try switching to session storage - could be related to cookies dropped due to a missing user gesture - eg [Intelligent Tracking Protection](https://webkit.org/blog/8828/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-2/)

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem. At least the Mobile Chrome in incognito mode is rejecting third party cookies, therefore silent login fails.